# Duplicate symbol when adding Google Analytics v3 and Google Maps 1.4.3 to my project

Tags: ios, google-maps, sdk, google-analytics, duplicate-symbol

I'm currently developing an app that uses maps. So a couple of weeks ago I added the Google Maps SDK v1.4.3 to my project. 
Worked just fine following the getting started instruction.
Today I need to add Google Analytics to my project so I downloaded the latest SDK (v3).
I followed the getting started instructions again but now when I try to build my project I get the errors bellow.

Do you have an idea how I can solve the problem ?

It seems that if I remove the -ObjC flag it builds but when I call a Google Maps function then it crash with an error : unrecognized selector ...

So I'm stuck. Can't I use both SDKs in the same project ?

Thanks guys

PS : my project is compatible from iOS 5. It works great with Google Analytics v2 !!!

```
duplicate symbol _convertInt64ToUInt64 in:
/Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _convertUInt64ToInt64 in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _convertInt32ToUInt32 in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _convertUInt32ToInt32 in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _logicalRightShift32 in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _logicalRightShift64 in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _decodeZigZag32 in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _decodeZigZag64 in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _encodeZigZag32 in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _encodeZigZag64 in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeDoubleSizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeFloatSizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeUInt64SizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeRawVarint64Size in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeInt64SizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeInt32SizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeRawVarint32Size in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeFixed64SizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeFixed32SizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeBoolSizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeStringSizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeGroupSizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeUnknownGroupSizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeMessageSizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeDataSizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeUInt32SizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeEnumSizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeSFixed32SizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeSFixed64SizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeSInt32SizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeSInt64SizeNoTag in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeDoubleSize in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeTagSize in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeFloatSize in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeUInt64Size in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeInt64Size in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeInt32Size in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeFixed64Size in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeFixed32Size in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeBoolSize in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeStringSize in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeGroupSize in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeUnknownGroupSize in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeMessageSize in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeDataSize in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeUInt32Size in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeEnumSize in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeSFixed32Size in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeSFixed64Size in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeSInt32Size in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeSInt64Size in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeMessageSetExtensionSize in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _computeRawMessageSetExtensionSize in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _LITTLE_ENDIAN_32_SIZE in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _LITTLE_ENDIAN_64_SIZE in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _BUFFER_SIZE in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(CodedInputStream.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
duplicate symbol _DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(CodedOutputStream.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
duplicate symbol _DEFAULT_RECURSION_LIMIT in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(CodedInputStream.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
duplicate symbol _DEFAULT_SIZE_LIMIT in:
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/Maps/ProtocolBuffers.framework/ProtocolBuffers(CodedInputStream.o)
    /Users/pprod3/Desktop/Dabrut/MapProject/MapProject/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GeneratedProtocolBufferFiles.o)
ld: 59 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: have you been able to solve this problem?

Comment: @Meik No. Do you have an idea ? Do you have the same problem ?

Comment: unfortunately, yes. I posted a question to the GA developer forum, let's see if there's some workaround. In the meantime, I continued with the previous Google Analytics SDK (v2) which seems to work fine.

Comment: @Meik oh ok. If you have an answer could you post here the answer please ? thanks

Comment: did you find out why this problem is?

Comment: I have the same problem. Cant find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I was integrating another library and ended up having the same problem. I figured that this becuase of the -all_load. So for me the solution was to get rid of that flag in in the debug and release pods **Pods.degug.xcconfig and Pods.release.xcconfig** files.

and that was it.

I hope this helps some one in the future.